# How can we compress .stl file in Angular 7/JavaScript?

Tags: angular

Is there any possible way to compress .stl files in angular/javascript.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried gzipping them?

Comment: No.. @wentjun. Actually is ter any way to compress the size of that .stl file while viewing

Comment: Is it loaded as a static file from your servers or something? I am thinking of compressing it before you upload the file to your cloud server, you know what i mean?

Comment: @wentjun.. Yeah the .stl file will come from cloud server

Comment: the file size would be around 500mb size. So it would be performance issue so i need to compress while viewing that. Here I am using CAD viewer

Comment: No, I mean, compressing it as part of your build process. Meaning, you compress it before uploading your built files onto your cloud server. This way, everytime the user access the route, or access your web app, it will download the compressed gzip format instead of the full payload